# Under what condition(s) is a body a wave or a particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I want answer to the above question in Quantum Theory

Comment: The above question is not a meaningful question in Quantum Theory.

Comment: Some might answer this question with "Yes." There are *instances* in which it behaves like one or the other, but to say that it *is* one or the other (under any condition) is probably just misleading/wrong.

Comment: Every "thing" in the universe is the result of the dynamics of what we call "quantum fields". Whether these fields produce wave or particle like behavior is observer and observation dependent. In extreme cases, the same "object" can appear as a wave to one observer and as a particle to another (although not at the same time). It is therefor better to always look at nature as based on a single, unified "field" and to assign the special  "wave" and "particle" labels to the observer, rather than the quantum field.

Answer (score 2):

**Never**

An entity may behave similarly enough to a wave as to permit predicting its behavior using wave mechanics, or it may behave similar enough to a particle as to permit predicting its behavior using particle mechanics, but nothing is ever considered to be 100% one way or the other.  It merely gets close enough to behaving one way that you get away with approximations.

There is also a thing called a Wave Function, but this is typically not treated as the same thing as "wave" in terms of "wave/particle duality."  Typically when one talks of wave/particle duality, one is talking about classical behaviors, and many of the "paradoxes" involving wave/particle duality such as the double slit experiments merely demonstrate that thinking about entities as classic particles or like classic waves fails to properly capture the behaviors we can observe, while quantum mechanics does a much better job of capturing the behaviors we observe.

A reasonable intuitive approach can be taken by looking at what are often called "wave packets," which in this case refer to the wave function (not the wave/particle behaviors):

[image]

If a packet is highly localized in space, and remains so, you'll find the packet exhibits more particle like behaviors.  If a packet is highly localized in frequency, and remains so, you'll find the packet exhibits more wave like behaviors.  If does not exhibit a clear "preference" for being viewed as localized in space or localized in frequency, it's in that nether region where neither particle nor wave properly describes the behaviors of the entity.